# Update id value in table using cursors in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cursors

I've a table named `sample` with content like below but with 100's of entries.

```
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id | title          | status      |
+----+----------------+-------------+
|  0 | Abcd           | active      |
|  0 | Alsd           | active      |
|  0 | Asad           | inactive    |
|  0 | Awer           | active      |
|  0 | Awer           | active      |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

I want to update it and assign each title a unique id starting from **101**.
So, that it looks like the table below -

```
+-----+----------------+-------------+
| id  | title          | status      |
+-----+----------------+-------------+
| 101 | Abcd           | active      |
| 102 | Alsd           | active      |
| 103 | Asad           | inactive    |
| 104 | Awer           | active      |
| 105 | Awer           | active      |
+-----+----------------+-------------+
```

How to do it using sql cursors?

Comment: MySQL <> MS SQL Server

Comment: This sounds like a job for an identity column.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Are titles in alphabetical order?

Comment: titles are in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_Number as below:

```
Update d
    Set Id = Nid
    from ( Select *, Nid = 100 + Row_number() over(order by title) 
            from #data ) d
```

Comment: Its giving an error
``You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ( Select *, Nid = 100 + Row_number() over(order by title)
            fro' at line 3``

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from ( Select *, Nid = 100 + Row_number() over(order by title) fro' at line 3